# In PowerShell, how can I test if a variable holds a numeric value?

Tags: powershell

In PowerShell, how can I test if a variable holds a numeric value?

Currently, I'm trying to do it like this, but it always seems to return `false`.

```
add-type -Language CSharpVersion3 @'
    public class Helpers {
        public static bool IsNumeric(object o) {
            return o is byte  || o is short  || o is int  || o is long
                || o is sbyte || o is ushort || o is uint || o is ulong
                || o is float || o is double || o is decimal
                ;
        }
    }
'@

filter isNumeric($InputObject) {
    [Helpers]::IsNumeric($InputObject)
}

PS> 1 | isNumeric
False
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Modify your filter like this:

```
filter isNumeric {
    [Helpers]::IsNumeric($_)
}
```

`function` uses the `$input` variable to contain pipeline information whereas the `filter` uses the special variable `$_` that contains the current pipeline object.

Edit:

For a powershell syntax way you can use just a filter (w/o add-type):

```
filter isNumeric($x) {
    return $x -is [byte]  -or $x -is [int16]  -or $x -is [int32]  -or $x -is [int64]  `
       -or $x -is [sbyte] -or $x -is [uint16] -or $x -is [uint32] -or $x -is [uint64] `
       -or $x -is [float] -or $x -is [double] -or $x -is [decimal]
}
```

Comment: I think the native PowerShell route is the way I'll go. Thanks, @Christian.

Comment: Unable to find type [Helpers]

Comment: This is the first answer that really tests if a variable holds a numeric value. All others test if a _string_ represents a numeric value

Answer (score 59):

You can check whether the variable is a number like this: `$val -is [int]`

This will work for numeric values, but not if the number is wrapped in quotes:

```
1 -is [int]
True
"1" -is [int]
False
```

Comment: @Christian you're right. I was only thinking about the case in the question.

Comment: @CB that's because `1.5` is not an integer, it is a double... `1.5 -is [double]` evaluates to true

Comment: Also fails if the value is cast as a Int64.

Answer (score 44):

If you are testing a string for a numeric value then you can use the a regular expression and the `-match` comparison. Otherwise Christian's answer is a good solution for type checking.

```
function Is-Numeric ($Value) {
    return $Value -match "^[\d\.]+$"
}

Is-Numeric 1.23
True
Is-Numeric 123
True
Is-Numeric ""
False
Is-Numeric "asdf123"
False
```

Comment: I'm not testing a string, I'm testing a type. But ignoring that for the moment, how about negative values? And what about exponential values (3.24643e4)? Yeah, I know, I'm splitting hairs!

Comment: I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader. :) I just wanted to add this for people who may stumble on the question looking for checking numeric string values.

Comment: Well done @silent__thought, I was looking for exactly this.

Comment: `"1.2.3" -match "^[\d\.]+$"` --> True. `"^(\d+|\.\d+|\d+\.\d+)$"` would allow only one decimal separator. Returns true for "1", ".1", "1.1" and false for "1.", "1.1.1", "".

Comment: this regex is incorrect, `Is-Numeric .................` would be true

Answer (score 35):

You can do something like :

```
$testvar -match '^[0-9]+$'
```

or

```
$testvar -match '^\d+$'
```

Returns `True` if `$testvar` is a number.

Comment: This will only return true for positive integers

Comment: Check it '00:03:34,00 --> 00:03:36,80' -match '[0-9]+$'
5 -match '[0-9]+$'

Answer (score 18):

If you want to check if a string has a numeric value, use this code:

```
$a = "44.4"
$b = "ad"
$rtn = ""
[double]::TryParse($a,[ref]$rtn)
[double]::TryParse($b,[ref]$rtn)
```

Credits go [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/549c9432-9708-4711-9d4b-a03b512f8c20/how-can-i-check-if-variable-is-a-letter-or-number?forum=winserverpowershell)

Answer (score 13):

```
PS> Add-Type -Assembly Microsoft.VisualBasic
PS> [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Information]::IsNumeric(1.5)
True
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.information.isnumeric.aspx

Comment: I thought this was pretty neat until I realised that it would return true for a string that was numeric such as `"1.23"` which is not what I want. I want to know if the type of the actual object is a numeric type, not whether or not it can be coerced to a numeric type. Thanks for a useful tip though, I can see where that will be very handy.

Answer (score 10):

-is and -as operators requires a type you can compare against. If you're not sure what the type might be, try to evaluate the content (partial type list):

```
(Invoke-Expression '1.5').GetType().Name -match 'byte|short|int32|long|sbyte|ushort|uint32|ulong|float|double|decimal'
```

Good or bad, it can work against hex values as well (Invoke-Expression '0xA' ...)

Comment: That's a neat solution. For the context I need to use it though, `Invoke-Expression` could be quite dodgy!

Comment: Try{(Invoke-Expression '-123s.456e-789 ').GetType().Name -match 'byte|short|int32|long|sbyte|ushort|uint32|ulong|float|double|decimal'}Catch{$false}---Although you solution is almost perfect and flexible

Answer (score 6):

```
filter isNumeric {
    $_ -is [ValueType]
}
```

-

```
1 -is [ValueType]
True
"1" -is [ValueType]
False
```

-

```
function isNumeric ($Value) {
    return $Value -is [ValueType]
}

isNumeric 1.23
True
isNumeric 123
True
isNumeric ""
False
isNumeric "asdf123"
False
```

-

```
(Invoke-Expression '1.5') -is [ValueType]
```

Comment: PS> [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::CreateInstance -is [valuetype] (True)

Comment: PS> [char]"a" -is [valuetype] (True)

Comment: This is the right answer!

Comment: @x0n I don't know why but although your tests are ... true the function isNumeric correctly returns $false for both your cases. VERY strange but I'm also very tired.

Comment: This is by far the best and most succinct PowerShell solution. Nicely done!

Answer (score 4):

```
$itisint=$true
try{
 [int]$vartotest
}catch{
 "error converting to int"
 $itisint=$false
}
```

this is more universal, because this way you can test also strings (read from a file for example) if they represent number. The other solutions using -is [int] result in false if you would have "123" as string in a variable. This also works on machines with older powershell then 5.1

Comment: It’s always valuable to explain your code, but that’s especially true in a case like this where there’s a highly-rated accepted answer from eight years ago. Why is your approach preferred over the accepted answer? Do you mind updating your answer with more details?

Comment: If you are using `Read-Host` the result is always a string so you need to perform a check to see if the input even *is* numeric before converting. Generating and catching exceptions as flow control is always bad due to the amount of stuff done behind the scenes. The powershell way would be `$converted = $myInput -as [int]`. `$converted` will be `$null` if it could not convert, or the number if it was successful

Answer (score 3):

Thank you all who contributed to this thread and helped me figure out how to test for numeric values.  I wanted to post my results for how to handle negative numbers, for those who may also find this thread when searching...

Note: My function requires a string to be passed, due to using Trim().

```
function IsNumeric($value) {
# This function will test if a string value is numeric
#
# Parameters::
#
#   $value   - String to test
#
   return ($($value.Trim()) -match "^[-]?[0-9.]+$")
}
```

Comment: This will return true for version numbers like "9.3.4", you'd be better served by a regex like `^[-+]?([0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+\.?)$` which will validate you have only an optional plus/minus; numbers and an single optional decimal point.

Answer (score 3):

If you know the numeric type you want to test against (such as `int` for example in the code below), you can do it like this:

```
> [bool]("42" -as [int])
True
> [bool](42 -as [int])
True
> [bool]("hi" -as [int])
False
```

But note:

```
> [bool](42.1 -as [int])
True
```

**Careful!:**

It was pointed out that the code above fails to identify `0` as an `int`. You would need to add a guard for `0`:

```
> $n -eq 0 -or $n -as [int]
```

Where `$n` is the object you are testing.

Comment: I like this one.  Or `'11' | where { $(if ($_ -as 'int') { 10 -le $_ }) }`

Comment: Unfortunately:  `[bool](0 -as [int])` is `False`.

Comment: @HankSchultz thanks. That is a good bug to find. I have added a note at the end.

Comment: @dan-gph, to be clear, it isn't failing to recognize `0` as an `int`.  Instead, it's _casting_ `0` to `False`.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this topic while working on input validation with read-host. If I tried to specify the data type for the variable as part of the read-host command and the user entered something other than that data type then read-host would error out. This is how I got around that and ensured that the user enters the data type I wanted:

```
do
    {
    try
        {
        [int]$thing = read-host -prompt "Enter a number or else"
        $GotANumber = $true
        }
    catch
        {
        $GotANumber = $false
        }
    }
until
    ($gotanumber)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"-123.456e-789" -match "^\-?(\d+\.?\d*)(e\-?\d+)?$|^0x[0-9a-f]+$"
```

or

```
"0xab789" -match "^\-?(\d+\.?\d*)(e\-?\d+)?$|^0x[0-9a-f]+$"
```

will check for numbers (integers, floats and hex).

Please note that this does not cover the case of commas/dots being used as separators for thousands.

Answer (score 1):

Each numeric type has its own value. See TypeCode enum definition:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.typecode?view=netframework-4.8
Based on this info, all your numeric type-values are in the range from 5 to 15.
This means, you can write the condition-check like this:

```
$typeValue = $x.getTypeCode().value__
if ($typeValue -ge 5 -and $typeValue -le 15) {"x has a numeric type!"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Testing if a value is numeric or a string representation of a numeric value.

```
function Test-Number 
{
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                   Position=0)]
        [ValidatePattern("^[\d\.]+$")]
        $Number
    )

    $Number -is [ValueType] -or [Double]::TryParse($Number,[ref]$null)
}
```

Testing if a value is numeric.

```
function Test-Number 
{
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                   Position=0)]
        [ValidatePattern("^[\d\.]+$")]
        $Number
    )

    $Number -is [ValueType]
}
```

Comment: `$n=0; [Double]::TryParse('1e2', [ref]$n)` will parse it as a string representation of a number, but your functions will fail it. Same with negative numbers.