# User input validation in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, validation

I have this piece of code in PowerShell. I need user input validation to integer with writing output saying what is wrong with the input and expecting correct input.

```
$FromObj = "Please input object number"
$FromInput = Read-Host $FromObj

while(($FromInput -isnot [int])) {
    #I also want to put in the while that the input has to be an integer, -gt 0, and -lt 800
    Write-Output "Your input has to be a number."
    $FromInput = Read-Host $FromObj
    }
if ($FromInput -le 0) {
    Write-Output "Your input has to be a number greater than 0!"
    $FromInput = Read-Host $FromObj
    }
elseif ($FromInput -ge 800) {
    Write-Output "Your input has to be a number less than 800!"
    $FromInput = Read-Host $FromObj
    }
else {
    $FromInput = $FromInput -as [int]
    }
```

However, this is not working for me. Could you help me with validating it with writing outputs as the ones displayed above?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if string contains numeric value in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51171410/check-if-string-contains-numeric-value-in-powershell)

Comment: I think IsNumeric does not work for me, I need an integer validation only. I do not know if I am right about this but is there a way to validate it to an integer?

Comment: The first answer (`$FromInput -match "^\d+$"`) will do that for you, after you've confirmed the string contains an integer, you just need to convert it to one: `[int]$FromInput`. Replace your `($FromInput -isnot [int])` with `!($FromInput -match "^\d+$")` and put a `$FromInput = [int]$FromInput` before your first `if`

Comment: You were absolutely right! As usual I was wrong. Your answer works a charm. I sincerely apologize and appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [Nicks's link in comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68056955/user-input-validation-in-powershell#comment120287985_68056955) already provides different right answers to your question i.e.: using `regex` to match `\d+` (digits) or using `[int]::TryParse(...)` but to explain why your code is not working:

- `Read-Host` will store user input as `string` unless you manipulate it which is what you were already doing on your last condition (the `else {...}` statement).

This is why you never get past the `$FromInput -isnot [int]` condition.

To fix the code you could simply attempt to store user input `-as [int]` since the beginning and since you have 3 `Read-Host` on your code you could save the user input attempt `-as [int]` in a [`ScriptBlock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks?view=powershell-7.1) which then can be easily executed as many times as needed:

```sh
$FromObj = "Please input object number"
$giveMeNumber = { (Read-Host $FromObj) -as [int] }
$FromInput = & $giveMeNumber

while($FromInput -isnot [int]) {
    Write-Output "Your input has to be a number."
    $FromInput = & $giveMeNumber
}
if ($FromInput -le 0) {
    Write-Output "Your input has to be a number greater than 0!"
    $FromInput = & $giveMeNumber
}
elseif ($FromInput -ge 800) {
    Write-Output "Your input has to be a number less than 800!"
    $FromInput = & $giveMeNumber
}
```

Note, even though this works, the statement is not entirely correct since you're breaking out of the `while loop` after the input `is [int]` the user could force an incorrect input.

Try this instead which will execute indefinitely until right input:

```
Clear-Host
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
$FromObj = "Please input object number"

$scriptBlock = {
    try
    {
        $FromInput = [int](Read-Host $FromObj)

        # Note I'm using Write-Host instead of Write-Ouput, this is because
        # we don't want to store the invalid inputs messages in the
        # $userInput variable.
        if ($FromInput -le 0) {
            Write-Host "Your input has to be a number greater than 0!"
            & $scriptBlock
        }
        elseif ($FromInput -ge 800) {
            Write-Host "Your input has to be a number less than 800!"
            & $scriptBlock
        }
        else {
            $FromInput
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Host "Your input has to be a number."
        & $scriptBlock
    }
}

$userInput = & $scriptBlock
```

Comment: Soooo as usual, I was wrong. Both yours and Nick's answers did exactly what I had in mind. With the lack of description in my question you still nailed it guys. Srsly, dunno how you do it. Think you're mindreading sometimes, you're that good. Respect!

Comment: @Sv3n If this answer was helpful to you, please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) as it may help others in the future.